Unable to access folders on Windows 11, Access denied on a Local administrator account
I have one default user with administrator permissions on my Windows 11 laptop. I have never had any issues with installing or accessing anything.
Recently I have installed NordVPN, Qbittorrent etc., and after that I am unable to access a few subfolders inside the folder where I installed these 2 applications.
The context menu has changed as well for this folder as now it only allows a new folder creation with administrator permission required to create it.
I have two drives: C and D.
The path for the softwares folder is: D:\Softwares
The path for HidHide folder is: D:\Softwares\HidHide
The context menu in the Softwares folder where I install all my softwares
For example, when I try to open HidHide from its shortcut on desktop, it gives this error:
The error I get when I try to open Hidhide from its shortcut
Going inside the hidhide folder, there is a subdirectory called X64 which contains the .exe file, which I am unable to open as well. Opening it gives the following error:
Permission denied when I try to open the X64 sub-folder in the Hidhide folder
Picture of the security tab for this folder
What happens when you click continue on the security tab
I am able to access a few other .exe files installed in this folder via the shortcuts such as DS4Windows but a few applications such as HidHide are causing problems. Can anyone guide me regarding solving this problem?

You need to take ownership of D:\Softwares, apply it recursively, then give your user Full permissions to it, applying that recursively as well. Once done you'll be able to access the directory and all subdirectories.

In this folder's properties, Administrators accounts and default account (my local account is administrator) has full access but then Users (Faisal/Users) does not have full access. Trying to give permission to this last option fails with error: "Failed to enumerate objects in container. Access is denied"

Try doing so via an Admin terminal, as it's an ACL issue. If still unable to do so and getting an error, please add to your question the output of (within a codebox): icacls <directory path>
